# Double switch potentiometer

Tags: switches, potentiometer

I'm looking for a type of potentiometer (ideally about 500k) that has a feelable click switch at both ends. I have only found ones with a single on/off switch. What's the term I need to look for?

Comment: That sounds like a custom-build. I don't think they're a standard part. What's it used for?

Answer (score 1):

The key words you should look for are “modular potentiometer”.

You stack various options of parts to build a pot to meet your requirements, and maybe that will be an available combination. I notice some (eg. Series 389 from State) specify only one switch per shaft maximum so you still may not find what you need.